# Java && || operators precedent

Tags: java, if-statement

I need help with one if condition in java code

```
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String sHeaderStatus = "1";
            Boolean hasButton = false;
            Boolean editableLineStatus =true;
            String sFrom = "REQ";
            int canChangeSupplier = 0;
            if ((sHeaderStatus.equals("1") || canChangeSupplier == 1 && 
            (sHeaderStatus.equals("10") || sHeaderStatus.equals("14") || sHeaderStatus.equals("85") || sHeaderStatus.equals("86") || sHeaderStatus.equals("87"))
            || hasButton && editableLineStatus && !sHeaderStatus.equals("85")) || sFrom.equals("APPROVAL")) {
                String valdiaton ="true11";
            System.out.println(valdiaton);              
            }       
        }
```

result is true11

```
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String sHeaderStatus = "1";
            Boolean hasButton = false;
            Boolean editableLineStatus =false; //changed this one to false
            String sFrom = "REQ";
            int canChangeSupplier = 0;
            if ((sHeaderStatus.equals("1") || canChangeSupplier == 1 && 
            (sHeaderStatus.equals("10") || sHeaderStatus.equals("14") || sHeaderStatus.equals("85") || sHeaderStatus.equals("86") || sHeaderStatus.equals("87"))
            || hasButton && editableLineStatus && !sHeaderStatus.equals("85")) || sFrom.equals("APPROVAL")) {
                String valdiaton ="true11";
            System.out.println(valdiaton);
                
            }
            
        }
```

result is still true11

I am not able to understood the issue.

Per my understanding...

```
sHeaderStatus.equals("1") || canChangeSupplier == 1 // gave true
(sHeaderStatus.equals("10") || sHeaderStatus.equals("14") || sHeaderStatus.equals("85") || sHeaderStatus.equals("86") || sHeaderStatus.equals("87"))
            || hasButton   // gave false
```

become `true && false && true && true`

Similarly second code would become  `true && false && false &&true`

Am not sure how this become true and below line printed.

Comment: Did you try debugging this code to verify what is actually happening? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: what makes you believe that the languages java and javascript are the same?

Comment: You're literally printing `true11` each time, so are you trying to ask why anything gets printed at all?

Comment: The first code becomes `true || true`, while the second becomes `true || false`; if you want to make sure Java understands the way you want things grouped, add parentheses to make it explicit.

Comment: FWIW, you could simplify  all the equals checks with something like `sHeaderStatus.matches("10|14|8[5-7]")`

Comment: IMHO: you should *always* use additional parentheses with expressions involving a mix of `||` and `&&` operators.

Comment: @oneCricketeer. Yes i am not trying to understand how if condition met to the print inside code.

Comment: I am tryi g to understand how these. Conditions works.. per me it start from left to right..

Comment: @MC Emperor yes i would use it..but this snippet is from one work project.

Comment: As Scott said above, Both are OR-d with true, so both will print the output. Maybe you should explain how you came up with the `true && false && true && true`?

Answer (score 0):

[`&&` happens before `||`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Write the code like this

```
if (
  (
    sHeaderStatus.equals("1")
    || canChangeSupplier == 1 && (sHeaderStatus.equals("10") || sHeaderStatus.equals("14") || sHeaderStatus.equals("85") || sHeaderStatus.equals("86") || sHeaderStatus.equals("87"))
    || hasButton && editableLineStatus && !sHeaderStatus.equals("85")
  ) 
  || sFrom.equals("APPROVAL")
)
```

You can see that you always will have `(something) || false` with the values given.

And changing only `editableLineStatus` will modify only the operator "grouping" for `hasButton && editableLineStatus && !sHeaderStatus.equals("85")`.

However, regardless of what you change that to, you have `sHeaderStatus.equals("1")`, which is true, resulting in logic of

`(true || (false && false) || (false && true/false && true)) || false`

which, in total, is true, therefore entering the conditional